# Add method at runtime that depends on methods with annotations in same class

Tags: java, reflection, annotations, runtime

Currently my listener requires a switch tree to call internal methods.

```
public class Car{


   public void listener(String e){
      if(e.equals("Honk"))
        this.blowHorn();
   }

   @Honk
   private void blowHorn(){...}

}
```

Is it possible to leverage reflections and method annotations so that the listener method can be generated at run time? It would switch based on if the input equals the method annotation.This is better than using plain reflection because it reduces overhead.

Comment: What are You trying to accomplish?

Comment: The method would not be generated at runtime. But you could implement it so that it would dynamically call a method, yes. WHat have you tried? It doesn't sound too difficult.

Comment: I want to stay away from using reflection at runtime to reduce overhead. Ideally it would only need to reflect once

Answer (score 2):

*********************Answer with Refelection***********************

First you would declare your new annotation as so:

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface CarListener{
    public String carAction();
}
```

So that in your class Car you would have:

```
public class Car {

    //Here you´ll be looking at all the methods  you have in the class Car (I´d advice to 
    // put them in another class, so as to keep it clean, I didn´t do it here in order to
    // explain it better. These methods have the corresponding annotation you created

    public void listener(String e) { 
        Method[] methods = Car.class.getMethods();
            for(Method method:methods) {

        //Now that you have all the methods all you need is to figure which one you want
        // you´ll do that according to the "e" string, which represents the car action (for 
        // example "Honk") I´d also advice you to rename that too.

            if(rightMethod(method, e))

                //Now that you have found it, then you invoke the method, "call it"
                // which is what you wre doing in the previos code with "this.blowHorn()"

                return invokeMethod(method);
        }
        //This will help you in case you did NOT find the correct method, it´s just help 
        // if you don´t put it in it won´t break your code
        // fun fact about RuntimExceptions: you don´t have to declare them, meaning
        // you dont have to add them as "throws" or catch

        throw new RuntimeException("No listener found for car Action"+e);
    }

    private boolean rightMethod(Method method, String expression) {

    //First if asks if the method found has an annoation present, and if it does
    // then it asks if it corresponds to the annoation you created

        if (method.isAnnotationPresent(NewAnnotationInterfaceName.class))

    //if the method in fact has the annotation created all you are doing is asking what
    // carAction is associated to that method, you do that with the .carAction()

            return method.getAnnotation(NewAnnotationInterfaceName.class).carAction().equals(expression);
        return false;
    }


    //Now all you have to do is invoke it :) This just follows how to invoke a method
    // I won´t explain it

    private void  invokeMethod(Method method) {
        try {
            return method.invoke(Car.class.newInstance(), new Object[]{});
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException
                 | InvocationTargetException | IllegalArgumentException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Car.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        throw new RuntimeException("Could not invoke method");
    }


    @CarListener(carAction= "Honk")
    public void blowHorn() {  
        ...
    }

     @CarListener(carAction= "SomethingElse")
    public void someOtherAction() {  
        ...
    }

}
```

Hope that helps!

*********************Answer with Hashmap and Command design***********************

```
public abstract class CarAction {

    public abstract void execute(Car car){};

}

public class HonkAction extends CarAction{

    @Override
    public void execute(Car car) {
           car.blowHorn();
    }    

}

public class Car {

    private HashMap<String, CarAction> carActions;

    public Car() {
        ...
        initializeCarActions();
    }

    public void initializeCarActions() {
        this.carActions = new HashMap<>();
        this.carActions.put("Honk", new HonkAction());
        ...
    }

    public void listener(String e) {
        CarAction action = this.carActions.get(e);
        if(action!=null) action.execute(this);
    }

}
```

If you were to use this way, I´d suggest having someone inject the HashMap so that Car doesn´t have to depend on the CarActions (just the abstract class), either use a class to that or Guice. Also, this works if ALL the carActions just need "Car" in order to execute.

good luck!

Comment: ¿? Could anyone clear my question as to why my answer got a down vote? If I am wrong, I´m open to construcive criticism

Answer (score 0):

```
public listener(String e){
      if(e.equals("Honk"))
        this.blowHorn();
   }
```

Is not a proper Java method signature.

Again, if you use reflection, you don't need to generate the listener method "dynamically"

Comment: I would like to reduce overhead

Comment: Then write a code generator that would do it for you. And yes, it will have to use reflection as well. And you can have it called in the build process.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do this with annotations, you can do that with something like this:

```
public void listener(String e) {
    for (Method m : this.getClass().getDeclaredMethods()) {
        for (Annotation a : m.getDeclaredAnnotations()) {
            if (a.getClass().getSimpleName().equals(e)) {
                m.setAccessible(true); // Need to do this so we can run private methods
                m.invoke(this);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will call each method with annotations with names matching the name given. Sticking with this general design I'd suggest two core improvements:

- Pre-build an annotation <-> method map by doing the above but storing it in a annotation name -> method hashmap instead of calling it
- Take instances of an annotation  instead of Strings(`listener(Class<? extends Annotation> annotation)` instead of `listener(String e)`), so that you can just compare the input to the annotations on the method with equals instead of having to pull the names and compare the strings, which seems particularly nasty.

This is not a great design though; more typically you'd either hardcore these as a series of simple if statements (if there's a small number of options), or if there's quite a few options you'd use the something like the command pattern (encapsulate each callable method into an object), have each command register itself with a name on creation, and just store these in a map which you can then lookup from to find the relevant command.